# How secure are C# .NET and Java when connecting to external database and sending web requests?

Tags: java, c#

I am creating 3 applications that are written for different platforms (.NET (C#), Android (Java) and PHP). I'm using C# for the WPF application that is going to run on Windows PCs, PHP on the server side and Java for the mobile app. I am using a MySQL database where I'm storing all the information that 3 apps are going to be using.
I am using web requests to my Apache server (JSON and POST basically) when I need some specific stuff to do with PHP.
But, how safe is:

- When I'm connecting to the MySQL database via C# and Java?
- When I'm sending GET and POST web requests with C# and Java?

Can you somehow spy on the traffic that is going on between the device (PC / Android device) and the server and find out the user and the password of the database, or even get the post request parameters that the app is sending?
Because I know there are a lot of network-monitoring software and I wouldn't be surprised if this is possible.
If it is, then how to avoid it?

Comment: Let me first ask a question: "Are you transferring nuclear launch codes?". Trust me when I say that you should not even bother caring. This is one of those things that you can't stop, so don't bother trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"How secure are Java and C#?" isn't quite the right question, because the answer depends on what you do rather than the features in the languages. They both have plenty of good options for implementing various types of security in various ways. What really matters in your case is how the machines communicate.

> Can you somehow spy on the traffic that is going on between the device (PC / Android device) and the server and find out the user and the password of the database

Your clients (the PCs and Android devices) should not be connecting directly to your database. They should submit requests to your server, where you have much more control, and can authenticate clients and validate their data. The server then connects to the DB.

If the clients call the DB directly, not only are the credentials transmitted over the internet, but they must also be present locally on the client in some form. This means that someone could potentially crack your app and get access to them.

> or even get the post request parameters that the app is sending?

Yes, these can be intercepted and read. Again, preventing this is a matter of how you implement the communication. Use the HTTPS protocol, which you can do in both C# and Java, and the content of your requests will be protected from being intercepted by third parties along the way.

Comment: Thank you. This answer is helpful a lot! Everything is much clearer in my head now :)

Answer (score 1):

When your traffic is noticed or intercepted it will be freely interpretatable to the reader. You can see an example of such traffic in the console window of your browser, or if you want to view the actual application traffic use a proxy (such as [Fiddler2](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)).

If you want to prevent your traffic from being read, you have to take measures to ensure authorization and access control. You can do this by encrypting the traffic with TLS/SSL. If you have web-endpoints you can often enable https trough the libraries configuration. You may need to pass it as a parameter to the code that builds your connection.

Furthermore, it is best practice not to divulge sensitive information in your application output. You will want to use strong passwords and refrain from storing or sending these in plaintext.

I would also advice you to break down the need for securing in smaller bits.

Example:

You are using a lot of different technologies. These all have best practices and guidelines related to security. Separate your applications from your networking/operational assets. Encrypting your communication is a measure in your application. Whereas your MySQL configuration works in a different way entirely, mostly trough configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you connecting directly to your DB from the Android/WPF apps?

If the MySQL DB is sitting on a secure server, perhaps wrap the database calls/services in RESTful APIs implemented in your PHP solution, then call the APIs from your client apps, this also saves you from writing SQL statements and DB specific tasks in multiple languages (Java/C#)

not knowing your situation makes it hard though...